# ¿Cómo obtengo la primera fila de un array?

Tags: php, javascript

Usando la siguiente sentencia me muestra la columna `[0]` del array, no la fila.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)
{
    echo $row[0];
}
```

Quisiera sacar la primera fila del array, completa, no por columnas, espero me puedan ayudar.
O tal vez hacerlo con **JavaScript**, pero no tengo noción de cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Puedes utilizar el método `fetch()` si utilizas  [PDOStatement::fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php), si no, [mysql_fetch_row](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)

Comment: Puedes subir un ejemplo del array como lo necesitas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay algo que es importante entender cuando haces una consulta a la base de datos por medio de `mysqli` o de `PDO`: el recurso que es obtenido en caso de consulta exitosa **es un puntero hacia los datos** y **los métodos `fetch` sirven para moverse en ese puntero** Por eso generalmente los datos se leen dentro de un bucle (generalmente `while`) en el cual `fetch` va moviendo el puntero fila a fila.

Sabiendo eso, si quieres obtener la primera fila solamente puedes hacerlo simplemente así:

```
$firstRow=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
```

Al hacer eso, `mysqli_fetch_array` moverá el puntero a la primera fila, guardando los datos en la variable.

Si luego de esto haces por ejemplo:

```
$secondRow=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
```

Obtienes los datos de la segunda, si los hay. Lo interesante es `$resultado` que es un puntero (un recurso activo podríamos decir), al momento de ejecutar esta segunda llamada, estará en la primera línea y se moverá a la segunda.

Por lo tanto, si quieres solamente la primera fila, puedes obtenerla así:

```
$firstRow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
#Probamos los datos
var_dump($firstRow);
```

Si observas, he usado **un método más específico**, que es `mysqli_fetch_assoc`, para obtener los datos como array asociativo. El problema es que `mysqli_fetch_array`, salvo si no has indicado lo contrario en la configuración, te devolverá los datos como array asociativo y como array numérico, o sea, te traerá dos veces los mismos datos organizados de forma distinta.

Si en vez de un array asociativo necesitas uno numérico, entonces el **método específico para este caso es `mysqli_fetch_row`:

```
$firstRow=mysqli_fetch_row($resultado);
```

En definitiva, no uses nunca `mysqli_fetch_array` a no ser que por algún motivo necesites al mismo tiempo los datos en un array asociativo y numérico.

Otra nota sobre optimización es que, si lo único que te interesa de la consulta es la primera fila, puedes ponerle un `LIMIT 1`  a la consulta, para no estar trayendo datos que no vas a usar nunca. Eso tendrá consecuencias en el rendimiento de tu programa.

Comment: Muchas gracias por esa información, me ayudó a comprender lo que estaba haciendo.

Answer (score 1):

Recorre las columnas con un bucle y vas mostrando los valores

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)
{
    foreach($row as $value){
        echo $value . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solo debes aplicar la función `print_r` para imprimir la columna por completo si solo requieres la primera fila puedes agregar un `break` dentro del ciclo o una bandera que cambie cuando pase el primer recorrido del `while`, otra opcion es solo aplicar `mysqli_fetch_array` sin necesidad del `while`

Ejemplo:

```
$ini=true;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
{
    if($ini)
      print_r($row);//otra opcion var_dump
    $ini=false;
}
```

otra opción

```
if($resultado)//verifica si genero algún resultado
{
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
   foreach($row as $key=>$val)
     echo $key.":".$val.",";//muestra el nombre de la columna con su respectivo valor
}
```